# How to remove file from directory once upload is done?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to remove files from `app/` directory once upload response sent back to client. How can i achieve that task using nodejs ?

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'app/'}).single('file');
export function create(req, res) {

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
     console.log("error occurred");
    }else{
        console.log(req.file.path);
        var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path,'utf8');
        res.json(fileContent);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
 var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path,'utf8');
 fs.unlink(req.file.path);
 res.json(fileContent);
```

I'll recommend to not use Sync functions though:

```
fs.readFile(req.file.path,'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(data);
    fs.unlink(req.file.path);
});
```

Comment: Came here to say this, use unlink(), you can find the documentation here:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback